# JQuery not capturing form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using validationEngine to validate a form that is also launching a please wait modal.

Here's the code I am using to do this:

```
$("#main_form").validationEngine({
        onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
            if(status) {
                ShowProgressAnimation();
                form.validationEngine('detach');
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });
```

The issue I am having is I have a script that launches window.onbeforeunload.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
            window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt;
        });
```

Normally it would ignore form submissions, but in this case because of the form.submit it's not.

Is there a proper way to detect this and stop the window.onbeforeunload from loading if it detects the form.submit?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I also forgot to add I think this issue only exists in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The given script does not launch `window.onbeforeunload`, it just assigns a function to it.

If you want to prevent form submission, you need to return `false` in the submit handler:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt;
    return false;
});
```